The route is redirecting to the previous page:[GoRouter] redirecting to RouteMatchList#bd177(uri: /signIn,)
This is my app_router.dart and I am working on redirection now
In repo i have two methods

registerUser and registerbusiness where there is a bool if the request found or not and based on that i am applying the logic here
GoRouter goRouter(GoRouterRef ref) {
   final authRepository = ref.watch(firebaseAuthRepositoryProvider);

   void updateLastRoute(String routeName) async {
     final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
     await prefs.setString('lastRoute', routeName);
   }

 return GoRouter(
     initialLocation: "/signIn",
     debugLogDiagnostics: true,
     refreshListenable: GoRouterRefreshStream(authRepository.authStateChanges()),
     redirect: (context, state) async {
         final path = state.uri.path;
         final isLoggedIn = authRepository.currentUser != null;

         if (!isLoggedIn && path == "/") {
             return "/signIn";
         }
         final registrationRepo = await ref.watch(registrationRepoProvider.future);

         final isUserRegistered = await registrationRepo.registerUser();

         final isBusinessRegistered = await registrationRepo.registerBusiness();

         if (!isUserRegistered) {
             return '/setup/personal';
         } else if (!isLoggedIn) {
             return 'signIn';
         } else if (isLoggedIn && !isUserRegistered) {
             return '/setup/personal';
         } else if (isLoggedIn && isUserRegistered) {
             return '/home';
         } else if (isUserRegistered && !isBusinessRegistered) {
             return '/setup/business';
         }
     },
     routes: [
         GoRoute(
             path: '/home',
             name: AppRoute.home.name,
             pageBuilder: (context, state) {
                 updateLastRoute('/home');
                 return const NoTransitionPage(child: HomeScreen());
             },
         ),
         GoRoute(
             path: '/signIn',
             name: AppRoute.signIn.name,
             pageBuilder: (context, state) {
                 updateLastRoute('/signIn');
                 return const NoTransitionPage(child: PhoneNumber());
             },
             routes: [
                 GoRoute(
                     path: 'otp/:phoneNo',
                     name: AppRoute.otp.name,
                     pageBuilder: (context, state) {
                         final phoneNo = state.pathParameters['phoneNo']!;
                         return NoTransitionPage(child: OTPPage(phoneNumber: phoneNo));
                     },
                 ),
             ],
         ),
         GoRoute(
             path: '/setup/personal',
             name: AppRoute.personalSetup.name,
             pageBuilder: (context, state) {
                 updateLastRoute('/setup/personal');
   return const NoTransitionPage(child: AccountSetupScreen());
 },
),
GoRoute(
 path: '/setup/business',
 name: AppRoute.businessSetup.name,
 pageBuilder: (context, state) {
   updateLastRoute('/setup/business');
   return const NoTransitionPage(child: BusinessSetupScreen());
   },
  ),
 ],
);
}



I have accurately applied the navigation route like this:
if (context.mounted) {
            context.goNamed(AppRoute.otp.name, pathParameters: {
                  'phoneNo': phoneNumberController.text});

The error I am getting is :
[GoRouter] getting location for name: "otp", pathParameters: {phoneNo: 1234567890}
[GoRouter] going to /signIn/otp/1234567890
[GoRouter] redirecting to RouteMatchList#bd177(uri: /signIn, matches: [RouteMatch#9d1f6(route:                 GoRoute#a3290(name: "signIn", path: "/signIn"))])

If needed any other file or code please let me know

I guess: "path: 'otp/:phoneNo'" should be: "path: ' /otp/:phoneNo'."
